# Proper syntax for "botton_to" with parameters Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I, I have looked at the documentation and search articles, however, I can't seem to have the syntax right for "botton_to".

The following does work with the link_for:

```
<%= link_to "Compute Slots", :controller => :autoslots, :action => :new, :day_id => @day %>
```

Following the different advises from the doc and questions I have tried the following:

```
<%= button_to "Compute Slots", {:controller => :autoslots, :action => :new, :day_id => @day.id}, :class => "btn btn-default btnfixed", :method => :get %>

<%= button_to "Compute Slots", {:controller => :autoslots, :action => :new, :day_id => @day}, :class => "btn btn-default btnfixed", :method => :get %>

<%= button_to "Compute Slots", {:controller => :autoslots, :action => :new, :day_id => @day.id}, :class => "btn btn-default btnfixed", :method => :get %>

<%= button_to "Compute Slots", new_autoslot_path(@day), :class => "btn btn-default btnfixed", :method => :get %>

<%= button_to "Compute Slots", new_autoslot_path, :day_id => @day, :class => "btn btn-default btnfixed", :method => :get %>
```

And a few other permutations but I can't seem to have the syntax right to get the same result as the link_to syntax.

Anyone can help?

Comment: you can use button_to with url_for(controller: :autoslots, action: :new...etc) 
In Rails 4 action: is preferred instead of :action =>

Comment: @hmartinezd Clearly I don't get your syntax example since I am unable to form it with the day parameter without an exception.

Comment: @ssavard When the user presses the button, do you want them to arrive at /autoslots/new?day_id=n where n is some day_id?

Comment: @hmartinezd yes, that it what he link_to does and this is what I want to achieve. I just cannot form the same thing with bottom_to for some reasons.

Comment: Sorry, I think that I misunderstood your question. You can use html_options: {data: {day_id: @day}}. Really I don't have a rails enviroment with me right now, that's why I can't test it.